# MySQL - just adding ORDER BY an indexed field adds 5 minutes for just 52 records. Where to start?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, innodb

*EDIT 2: now that we have optimized the db and narrowed down in [MySQL - Why is phpMyAdmin extremely slow with this query that is super fast in php/mysqli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61972759/mysql-why-is-phpmyadmin-extremely-slow-with-this-query-that-is-super-fast-in-p)*

*EDIT 1: there are two solutions that helped us. One on database level (configuration) and one on query level. I could of course only accept one as the best answer, but if you are having similar problems, look at both.*

We have a database that has been running perfectly fine for years. However, right now, we have a problem that I don't understand. Is it a mysql/InnoDB configuration problem? And we currently have nobody for system maintenance (I am a programmer).

The tabel TitelDaggegevens is a few Gigs in size, about 12,000,000 records, so nothing extraordinary.

If we do:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TitelDaggegevens 
 WHERE fondskosten IS NULL 
   AND (datum BETWEEN 20200401 AND 20200430)
```

it runs fine, within a few tenths of a second.

The result: 52 records.

Also if we add `ORDER BY datum` or if we order by any other non-indexed field: all is well, same speed.

However, if I add `ORDER BY id` (id being the primary key), suddenly the query takes 15 seconds for the same 52 records.

And when I `ORDER BY` another indexed field, the query-time increases tot **4-6 minutes**. For ordering 52 records. On an indexed field.

I have *no clue* what is going on. EXPLAIN doesn't help me. I optimized/recreated the table, checked it, and restarted the server. All to no avail. I am absolutely no expert on configuring MySQL or InnoDB, so I have no clue where to start the search.

I am just hoping that maybe someone recognises this and can point me into the right direction.

`SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = 'TitelDaggegevens'`
Gives me:

[image: SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = 'TitelDaggegevens']

I know this is a very vague problem, but I am not able to pin it down more specifically. I enabled the logging for slow queries but the table slow_log stays empty. I'm lost.

Thank you for any ideas where to look.

This might be a help to someone who knows something about it, but not really to me, phpmyadmins 'Advisor':

[image: Advisor]

In the comments and a reaction were asked for EXPLAIN outputs:

1) Without `ORDER BY`  and with `ORDER BY datum` (which is in the WHERE and has an index):

[image: Without orderby]

2) With `ORDER BY` plus any field other than `datum` (indexed or not, so the same for both quick and slow queries).

[image: With order by with indexed fields]

The table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `TitelDaggegevens` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `isbn` decimal(13,0) NOT NULL,
 `datum` date NOT NULL,
 `volgendeDatum` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `prijs` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `prijsExclLaag` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `prijsExclHoog` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `stadiumDienstverlening` char(2) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `stadiumLevenscyclus` char(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `gewicht` double(7,3) DEFAULT NULL,
 `volume` double(7,3) DEFAULT NULL,
 `24uurs` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `UitgeverCode` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `imprintId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `distributievormId` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
 `boeksoort` char(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `publishingStatus` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
 `productAvailability` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
 `voorraadAlles` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `voorraadBeschikbaar` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `voorraadGeblokkeerdEigenaar` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `voorraadGeblokkeerdCB` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `voorraadGereserveerd` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `fondskosten` enum('depot leverbaar','depot onleverbaar','POD','BOV','eBoek','geen') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `ISBN+datum` (`isbn`,`datum`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `UitgeverCode` (`UitgeverCode`),
 KEY `Imprint` (`imprintId`),
 KEY `VolgendeDatum` (`volgendeDatum`),
 KEY `Index op voorraad om maxima snel te vinden` (`isbn`,`voorraadAlles`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `fondskosten` (`fondskosten`),
 KEY `Datum+isbn+fondskosten` (`datum`,`isbn`,`fondskosten`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16519430 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
```

Comment: Provide EXPLAIN output please

Comment: You're right, I should have anyway. So I just did. I hope it helps.

Comment: Also add EXPLAIN for ORDER BY another indexed field please. Looks like it's missing

Comment: Consider learning how to use covering indexes from this URL - https://blog.toadworld.com/2017/04/06/speed-up-your-queries-using-the-covering-index-in-mysql

Comment: All EXPLAIN outputs are exactly the same for all query with ORDER BY xxx , whether the xxx is indexed or not, except when the field is the datum field (which is also uses in the WHERE), then it's the same als without the ORDER BY.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have looked into it. Clever, and this might help me at some points! But not in this case. The weird thing is that there is an index on isbn + datum. (Just not on fondskosten.) Also: the queries/table/db never gave me a headache before in several years! So I guess something else is going on. That's why I repaired the table and rebooted the server. The virtual server (CentOs7) also has enough disk space. So I am lost, I can only think of something wrong in the configuration, but I have no good understanding of that.

Comment: And just to be sure: I added a covering index; it didn't change anything, alas.

Comment: Please post the TEXT results of the EXPLAIN your query, your entire slow query,  and SHOW CREATE TABLE (for-each-table); for analysis.  View profile, Network profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning. Please post 1st two pages of output of our findfragtables.sql for analysis. Version of MySQL?

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help. We will have a professional mysql specialist flown in. Several queries on different large tables all have become slow quite suddenly. this is not something that can be solved here. I googled a lot, tried a lot of tips here, nothing seems to help.

Comment: "Flown in"?  Wilson or I can probably help you a lot cheaper -- and remotely.

Comment: "ORDER BY another indexed field, the query-time increases tot 4-6 minutes" -- This was still 52 rows of output?  Let's see that query and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Haha rick, the flying was meant metaphorically. (English is my second language.) He turned some knobs for the good! We only have problems with this query (and similar on similar tables) WITHIN phpmyadmin. Which isn't too bad, our systems work flawlessly again. (Well the database at least.) Exploitfdate gave a good explanation about the query, we will now (not urgently) look into why phpmyadmin is so slow on certain queries and others not, whereas in normal php there is no problem. Thank you so much for your time and thoughts.

Comment: I learned a lot of useful stuff by discussing this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Have this to handle the `WHERE` entirely:

   ```
   INDEX(fondskosten, Datum)
   ```

Note: the `=` is first, then the range.

2. Fetch the `*`.  Note:  If there are big `TEXT` or `BLOB` columns that you don't need, spell out the `SELECT` list so you can avoid them.  They may be stored "off-record", hence take longer to fetch.
3. An optional `ORDER BY`.  If it is on `Datum`, then there is no extra effort.  If it is on *any* other column, then there will be a sort.  But a sort of 52 rows will be quite fast (milliseconds).

Notes:

- If you don't have `fondskosten IS NULL` or you have some other test, then all bets are off.  We have to start over in designing the optimal composite index.
- `USE/FORCE INDEX` -- use this as a last resort.
- Always provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` when needing to discuss a query.
- The `Advisor` has some good stuff, but without any clues of what is "too big", it is  rather useless.
- I *suspect* all the other discussions failed to realize that there are far more than 52 rows for the given `Datum` range.  That is `fondskosten IS NULL` is really part of the problem and solution.

Comment: These queries are actually generated in phpmyadmin. So we have very little control over them! There were other instances though.

Comment: We had found at the exact same time the same index. Also a few parameter changes helped enormously. Thank you for your explanation. I will take this in the back of my head.

Comment: Also we had a pro look into the db configuration, that helped with all other problems.

Comment: The only problem now we do not understand is that similar queries on similar tables like the one posted are ONLY in phpmyadmin slow. The process status is always 'Sending data...' for a long time. In php or directly in mysql everything runs VERY smoothly. Even without your index. Your index dus help with phpmyadmin. Any idea?

Comment: To add to the confusion:  without the index, only in phpmyadmin: changing the WHERE with a datum < 20200501 (52 records) becomes a 1000x quicker when adding one day to the range: datum < 20200502 giving 6000+ records. Any idea why?

Comment: PS. Your remark about the `=` first and then the range is so blatantly logical that I am bit ashamed I hadn't thought of it myself.

Comment: @Roemer - Interesting.  Many times, I have advised putting `=` first.  So, I assume that it is not 'blatantly logical'.  Can you give a brief explanation of why it is so logical?

Comment: Last time I looked at phpmyadmin, it seemed to be just a UI into the database, not a tool that is creating SQL.  Is it generating values like `20200401`?  And sometimes putting them in quotes?

Comment: No the values I enter in the forms. The way a date is entered has no influence, we checked that. I realise it's just a UI, but apparently there is something different how it connects to the db then what we normally do. It must be a buffering thing.

Comment: If the resultset is huge (thousands or millions of rows), the UI may download the data is chunks, rather than waiting for all of it to arrive.  Does this explain the difference?

Answer (score 1):

For people searching for tweaks in similar cases, these are the tweaks the specialist made to the db that sped it up considerably (mind you this is for a database with 100s of tables and MANY very complex and large queries sometimes joining over 15 tables but not super massive number of records. The database is only 37 gigabytes.

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=4
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2

tmp_table_size=64M
max_heap_table_size=64M

join_buffer_size=4M
sort_buffer_size=8M

optimizer_search_depth=5
```

The optimizer_search_depth was DECREASED to minimize the time the optimizer needs for the complex queries.

After restarting the server, (regularly) run all queries that are the result of running this query:

```
SELECT CONCAT('OPTIMIZE TABLE `', TABLE_SCHEMA , '`.`', TABLE_NAME ,'`;') AS query
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE DATA_FREE/DATA_LENGTH > 2 AND DATA_LENGTH > 4*1024*1024
```

(This first one better when the server is off line or has low use if you have large tables. It rebuilds and thus optimizes the tables that need it.)

And then:

```
SELECT CONCAT('ANALYZE TABLE `', TABLE_SCHEMA , '`.`', TABLE_NAME ,'`;') AS query
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE DATA_FREE/DATA_LENGTH > 2 AND DATA_LENGTH > 1*1024*1024
```

(This second querie-series is much lighter and less infringing but may still help speed up some queries by recalculating query strategies by the server.)

Comment: `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is, in most cases, useless for InnoDB tables.  Running `ANALYZE TABLE` is totally useless after `OPTIMIZE` since `OPTIMIZE` does an `ANALYZE`.  One use case for optimize is a bug `DELETE`.  But there are better ways to do that.  Let's discuss _that_ in another Q&A.

Comment: How much RAM do you have?  I see the buffer_pool is only 2G.

Comment: Is this an EAV schema?  And it is a 15-way self-join?  Or some other situation?

Comment: It's not how may records are _returned_; it's how many are _touched_.  This provides that info:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts

Comment: `DATA_FREE/DATA_LENGTH` is strange -- For `innodb_file_per_table=OFF`, it says "there is room to do the optimize" except that it ignores `Index_length`.  For `ON`, it may or may not be indicative of anything.

Comment: Hey Rick, the analyze is done on much more tables than the optimize, hence. We have 8GB of RAM. No EAV, just complex situations leading to complex data.

Comment: innodb_file_per_table=ON and then the DATA_FREE column shows the free space in bytes for InnoDB tables. Basically if the database is large and the free space takes up twice as much disk space as the data, defrag it by recreating. It works well.

Comment: How much spare RAM in the system?  Give most of it to the buffer_pool.

Comment: Also the number of records _touched_ are bigger (this number is the only difference in the EXPLAIN between the two dates) and yet with the more records it is much faster.

Comment: "Faster" _may_ be an artifact of caching.  Did you run the timing (for each case) twice?

Comment: Yes. It's not a caching effect. I did the thing from your link and it is very interesting and completely different from the EXPLAIN results.
The fast query (< 20200502 ) gives Handler_read_next 11728896 and Handler_icp_attempts 0, the slow query ( < 20200501 ) gives  Handler_read_next 26651 and Handler_icp_attempts 213197
So - as expected -  it is very clear that the engine takes a completely different approach to the two queries.  See also https://ibb.co/cCqdyjd https://ibb.co/bddprvF for the full results

Comment: Also very interesting considering the total number of records (regardless of fondskosten) between those dates is only 206286. Why 11,7 mln "Handler_read_next " ? The whole table has 11.4 mln records!

Comment: Rick, I continued the issue very clearly on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61972759/mysql-why-is-phpmyadmin-extremely-slow-with-this-query-that-is-super-fast-in-p

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ORDER BY uses 3 different optimization plans

1. `ORDER BY id` - Extra: `Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort`. MySQL uses `filesort` to resolve the `ORDER BY`. But rows are sorted already. So, it takes 15 second.
2. `ORDER BY Datum` or other non-indexed field - Extra: `Using index condition; Using where`. MySQL uses `Datum` index to resolve the `ORDER BY`. It takes few seconds.
3. `ORDER BY index_field` - Extra: `Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort`. MySQL uses `filesort` to resolve the `ORDER BY`. Rows are unsorted. It takes few minutes.

It's my suggestion. Only `EXPLAIN` can tells what's going on

[Influencing ORDER BY Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html#order-by-optimizer-control)

**UPD:**
Could you check this query with every `ORDER BY` clauses?

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TitelDaggegevens USE INDEX FOR ORDER BY (Datum)
 WHERE fondskosten IS NULL 
   AND (Datum BETWEEN 20200401 AND 20200430)
```

Also you may try to increasing the [sort_buffer_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size)

> If you see many `Sort_merge_passes` per second in `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` output, you can consider increasing the `sort_buffer_size` value to speed up `ORDER BY` or `GROUP BY` operations that cannot be improved with query optimization or improved indexing.
> On Linux, there are thresholds of 256KB and 2MB where larger values may significantly slow down memory allocation, so you should consider staying below one of those values.

Comment: Thank you! I added the EXPLAIN's to the question, It turns out there is a difference between ORDER BY and non-ORDER BY/ordering on the field in  the WHERE, but the results are the same for no delay and 6 minutes delay...

Comment: I tried the increasing of the sort_buffer_size before, it had, alas, no effect.

Comment: I tried your query. `USE INDEX FOR ORDER BY (datum)` makes everything goes fast if you `ORDER BY` any field. Basically: telling MySQL to ignore all the "appropriate" indexes makes it go fast. (`ORDER BY isbn` is slow if it uses any index with isbn as first field, but as second field or without it, it is fast.)

Comment: So it comes as no surprise that:  `SELECT id FROM TitelDaggegevens WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM TitelDaggegevens WHERE datum > '20200331' AND datum < 20200501 AND fondskosten IS NULL) ORDER BY isbn` does it superquickly...

Comment: I've found Sergey Petrunia’s article [How MySQL executes ORDER BY](http://s.petrunia.net/blog/?p=24) which explains of how it works.

Comment: @Roemer  By your use of date selection BEFORE looking at the fondskosten content  eliminated many reads of the table.  Please post your current EXPLAIN results.  Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Since we have troubles that we never had before in numerous places with numerous queries in the db, it's NOT about this single query (which came from phpMyAdmin btw, not from our code, just trying to look up some data). We will have a professional mysql specialist flown in.  I googled a lot, tried a lot of tips here, nothing seems to help.

Comment: `ORDER BY id` is an extra sort.  But sorting 52 rows takes an insignificant amount of time.

Comment: Just to be sure I added the table structure to the question.

Comment: @ExploitFate - (Be cautious of blogs that have not changed in 13 years, like Petrunia's.  In this case, I think blog is still mostly valid.)  Note:  `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` gives more info today.