# MySQL - Why is phpMyAdmin extremely slow with this query that is super fast in php/mysqli?

Tags: mysql, configuration, phpmyadmin, mariadb

***Edit***: see also my answer, the main difference is the `LIMIT` that phpmyadmin adds, but I still don't understand and phpmyadmin is still slower than mysqli.

On our database (+web) server we have a *huge* difference in performance when doing a query in phpmyadmin vs doing it from php (mysqli) or directly on the mariadb server. 60 seconds vs < 0.01 seconds!

This query functions quite well:

```
SELECT * FROM `TitelDaggegevens` 
WHERE `datum` > '2020-03-31' AND datum < '2020-05-02' AND `fondskosten` IS NULL 
ORDER BY isbn;
```

But, *only* in phpMyAdmin, the query becomes extremely slow when we change `2020-05-02` to `2020-05-01`.

`SHOW PROCESSLIST` shows that the queryu is mainly `Sending data` whilst running.

Following [mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts) I did the following query-series:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT-query above with one of the two dates;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

The differences are fascinating. (I left out all the values equal to 0 in all cases). And consistent over time.

```
|                        how:   |     server/MySqli       |      phpMyAdmin 
|         date used in query:   | 2020-05-02 | 2020-05-01 | 2020-05-02 | 2020-05-01
|           records returned:   | 6912       | 1          | 6912       | 1
|                  avg speed:   | 0.27s      | 0.00s      | 0.52s      | 60s (!)
| Variable_name                 | Value      | Value      | Value      | Value
| Handler_icp_attempts          | 213197     | 206286     | 213197     | 0
| Handler_icp_match             | 6912       | 1          | 6912       | 0
| Handler_read_next             | 6912       | 1          | 26651      | 11728896 (!)
| Handler_read_key              | 1          | 1          | 151        | 4
| Handler_commit                | 1          | 1          | 152        | 5
| Handler_read_first            | 0          | 0          | 1          | 1
| Handler_read_rnd_next         | 0          | 0          | 82         | 83
| Handler_read_rnd              | 0          | 0          | 0          | 1
| Handler_tmp_write             | 0          | 0          | 67         | 67
```

The EXPLAIN results are the **same** in all cases (phpmyadmin/mysqli/putty+mariadb).

```
    [select_type] => SIMPLE
    [table] => TitelDaggegevens
    [type] => range
    [possible_keys] => fondskosten,Datum+isbn+fondskosten
    [key] => Datum+isbn+fondskosten
    [key_len] => 3
    [ref] => 
    [Extra] => Using index condition; Using filesort
```

The only difference is in rows:

```
    [rows] => 422796 for 2020-05-01
    [rows] => 450432 for 2020-05-02
```

**The question**

Can you give us any **directions** in where we should could look to solve this problem? We've worked for a week to optimize the mariadb server (now optimal, except in phpmyadmin) and narrow some of our problems down to the example underneath. We use phpmyadmin a lot but have little to no experience with what is under the surface (like how it connects to the db).

**About the indexing/ordering**

In the slow query, if we change the `ORDER BY` from the indexed `isbn` field to a non-indexed field or leave out the `ORDER BY` altogether, everything has its normal lightning speed again. Changing the `ORDER BY` to the primary key `id` makes it slow too, but still 10x as fast as with the indexed `isbn` field.

*We *know* we can solve this particular query by better indexing, which we already have ready to implement. However, we want to know what causes the different times within phpmyadmin vs mysqli/directly.*

**The details:**

TitelDaggegevens contains < 11mln records, not even 3Gb, and has been OPTIMIZEd (rebuild)

The table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `TitelDaggegevens` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `isbn` decimal(13,0) NOT NULL,
 `datum` date NOT NULL,
 `volgendeDatum` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `prijs` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `prijsExclLaag` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `prijsExclHoog` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `stadiumDienstverlening` char(2) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `stadiumLevenscyclus` char(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `gewicht` double(7,3) DEFAULT NULL,
 `volume` double(7,3) DEFAULT NULL,
 `24uurs` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `UitgeverCode` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `imprintId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `distributievormId` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
 `boeksoort` char(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `publishingStatus` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
 `productAvailability` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
 `voorraadAlles` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `voorraadBeschikbaar` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `voorraadGeblokkeerdEigenaar` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `voorraadGeblokkeerdCB` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `voorraadGereserveerd` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `fondskosten` enum('depot leverbaar','depot onleverbaar','POD','BOV','eBoek','geen') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `ISBN+datum` (`isbn`,`datum`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `UitgeverCode` (`UitgeverCode`),
 KEY `Imprint` (`imprintId`),
 KEY `VolgendeDatum` (`volgendeDatum`),
 KEY `Index op voorraad om maxima snel te vinden` (`isbn`,`voorraadAlles`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `fondskosten` (`fondskosten`),
 KEY `Datum+isbn+fondskosten` (`datum`,`isbn`,`fondskosten`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16519430 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
```

Configuration of our virtual web+database+mail server:

```
MariaDB 10.4 
InnoDB
CentOs7 
phpMyAdmin 4.9.5
php 5.6
Apache
```

Some important mariadb configuration parameters that we changed from what our virtual webserver had as default:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=4
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2

tmp_table_size=64M
max_heap_table_size=64M

join_buffer_size=4M
sort_buffer_size=8M

optimizer_search_depth=5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've had a specialist look at it, additional to all your tips.

It turned out after MANY tests that the `LIMIT 0,25` that phpMyAdmin added was the ONLY thing that caused the extreme delay. The expert could find NO differences between mysqli/phpmyadmin and executing it directly on the mariadb server.

Sometimes a VERY small difference in query (like adding a LIMIT for a query that returns only one record anyway) can cause a query to take 100.000 as long because it wil scan a whole index because the engine will see another strategy fit for that query. That is standard behaviour.

We have already found an index that eliminated this specific problem, but now we are also assured that there is nothing wrong with our DB. Something we were not sure of because it seemed extreme behaviour. So, much ado about nothing.

Comment: I have found that the MySQL tends to ignore `LIMIT`.  I wonder if MariaDB takes it into account, but screwed up in your 'MANY' examples.

Comment: MariaDB just takes a different approach based on many factors, and a very unlucky approach in this case. But the LIMIT and the specific date together were the reason it suddenly took 100.000x as long.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest difference, is **of course** that phpmyadmin adds a LIMIT to the query. That gives the main explanation. I can't believe that that wasn't the first thing we tried, I am very embarrassed.

However, the speed difference between phpMyAdmin and mysqli is still big, and the results are still different (2020-05-01 on server or mysqli):

```
+----------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name              | Value    |
+----------------------------+----------+
| Handler_commit             | 1        |
| Handler_read_first         | 1        |
| Handler_read_next          | 11733306 |
| rest                       | 0        |
+----------------------------+----------+
```

Speed with `limit` and 2020-05-02: all around 0.17-0.2
Speed with `limit` and 2020-05-01:
php/mysqli: claimed: 3.5sec but the page loads for about 30 secs
putty/mariadb: claimes also 3.5 secs but shows results after about 30 secs
phpmyadmin:  claimed and real time about 60secs

Also the EXPLAIN does change considerably with a LIMIT:

(with rows 1268 with datum<20200501 and 1351 with datum<20200502)

```
+------+-------------+------------------+-------+------------------------------------+------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table            | type  | possible_keys                      | key        | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+------------------+-------+------------------------------------+------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | TitelDaggegevens | index | fondskosten,Datum+isbn+fondskosten | ISBN+datum | 9       | NULL | 1351 | Using where |
+------+-------------+------------------+-------+------------------------------------+------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: We still can not see your most recent QUERY. SELECT ..... ;  Consider turning ON the GENERAL LOG before running the query in each.  Then turn off General Log, post the General Log output as well.  Thanks

Comment: I am sorry.  `SELECT * FROM TitelDaggegevens  WHERE datum > '2020-03-31' AND datum < '2020-05-02' AND fondskosten IS NULL  ORDER BY isbn LIMIT 0,25`. The query plus the limit.

Comment: Apparently the 30+ days requested pushed the optimizer in an unexpected direction.  Would the simple = (one day) selection, since you really on want 1 day's data, return results quicker?

Comment: Again, it's not about optimizing the query. A simple index will do that. Or leaving out the LIMIT. The main question is (by now): why does the query report taking 4 seconds while it actually takes 60 seconds?

Comment: I have the log file (thanks for the tip) but it is very long (also because of other stuff going on at the same time). During the minute the query takes, nothing is logged at all. So no help there. Mainly a lot of stuff that phpmyadmin needs to display the query after the query and a bit of preparation before. (Because I ran it from phpmyadmin.)

Comment: Also no differences in the log file between a fast and a slow query whatsoever (except for things needed to display the result in phpmyadmin). Basically it's `200526 13:02:39  31186 Query SHOW WARNINGS
   31186 Query SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS'  (3x this)
   31186 Query SELECT DATABASE()
   31186 Init DB admin_dvu
   31186 Query SELECT * FROM TitelDaggegevens WHERE datum > '2020-03-31' AND datum < '2020-05-01' AND fondskosten IS NULL ORDER BY isbn LIMIT 0,25
200526 13:04:04  31186 Query SHOW WARNINGS`

Comment: What is the geographical distance in KM or Miles of the 60 seconds you are referring to?  Would SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; tell you it was 'sending data'?  If so, it is packet delivery time most likely.  If you would post your logs to pastebin.com which has a higher size limit than SO we might be able to help you understand WHAT is going on.

Comment: The changelog for 4.9.5 suggests "As a reminder, phpMyAdmin 4.9 is in the long-term support phase where it
will only get important security fixes and critical bug fixes. Users are
suggested to migrate to version 5.0." by Isaac of phpMyAdmin.

Comment: We'd love to (first thing I tried) but we'd have to check/update about 1000+ php pages to php 7 first, since we are still on php 5.6.

Comment: Wilson, thank you again. There is zero physical distance. The 'Sending Data' turned out to happen even when executed directly at the server. Hence we concluded, also from log files, profiling, session status, that it is just a weird query strategy that mariaDB takes in this very specific case. We hired an expert who guaranteed that this is normal behaviour. An extra index solves this case and after a thorough analysis we found there is NO problem between phpmyadmin and our mariadb. Thank you SO much for your help, I've really learned a lot from your answers. I can do my own diagnostics now!

Comment: Wonderful.  View profile, Network profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.

Answer (score 0):

Consider making optimizer_search_depth=16 rather than 5
and

```
SELECT * FROM `TitelDaggegevens` 
WHERE `datum` BETWEEN '2020-03-31' AND '2020-05-02' AND `fondskosten` IS NULL 
ORDER BY ISBN;
```

Comment: Good call. But it was 16 when we encountered the problem first, we lowered it for other reasons. The BETWEEN doesn't make a difference (but it needs to be 2020-04-30 within the problem query). It would worry me a lot about the mariadb engine if it had made a difference. ;)

Comment: Another month's worth of data will make a difference in time required.  Have you considered in phpmyadmin, turning on profiling for the session to get details on what resources are being used?  Another level down in your search for the reason for time required.

Comment: For this kind of problem, posting the QUERY and the EXPLAIN (your QUERY) would be most helpful for the testing of phpmyadmin for the 2020-05-01 that had the high number of handler_read_next , please.

Comment: I know. That's why I originally put them both in the question and in the updated version (my own answer) ;)   Thank you Wilson, we will look into the profiling.

Comment: @WilsonHauck - (Nit pick) `BETWEEN` is inclusive, so `BETWEEN '2020-03-31'...` does not give the same range.

Comment: I predict that profiling will say 99% in some useless thing like "Sending data".

Answer (score 0):

You found a strange one, and did a good job of investigating.

Is there a way to get `EXPLAIN` from phpmyadmin?  If so, that might give another clue.

The Handler numbers strongly imply a different `EXPLAIN` was used.

Clearly phpmyadmin modifies the query (at least by adding the `LIMIT`).  I wonder if it messed with the query accidentally.  Did you have the Slowlog or the General log turned on at that time?  Either should have the SQL *as run*.

Replacing the index on just `(fondskosten)` with `INDEX(fondskosten, datum)` should improve performance.

("Sending data", as always, is useless information provided by the engine.)

Suggest filing a bug with mariadb.com.